# Cannot load static content in Django

Tags: django, configuration, static

I am setting up a beginner django app and I cannot make it display static content.  (css and jpg) files.  The documentation is confusing and I need some help at a very basic level.

My static files are located in: '/home/me/django_projects/myproject/site_media'.   Under here there are directories:  'images' and 'css'

I am getting 404 errors on everything static.   Even if I try to pull the file directly from:  http://localhost:8000/site_media/images/test_image.jpg

Here is the html code that I that is supposed to trigger static content:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Django Test </title>
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
   This is my body...   blah blah blah
   <p>Here is an image:  <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/media.jpg" alt="Foobar" />
</body>
```

Below are my settings files.  I've tried about every combination of media and static configuration I can think of.   Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

**File: settings.py**

```
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/me/django_projects/myproject/site_media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/home/me/django_projects/myproject/static",  
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

#...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'jim',
)
```

**File:  urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^customers/$', 'jim.views.index'),
    (r'^customers/(?P<customer_id>\d+)/$', 'jim.views.detail'),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/media'}),
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/media'}),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Does anyone see whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have two forward slashes:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
"{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/style.css"
```

would give you

```
"/static//css/style.css"
```

view the page source in the browser and see how the url is being written

Comment: Many Thanks!  This and the fact I was using media incorrectly below helped a bundle.  It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your config I would expect the file at:

http://localhost:8000/media/images/test_image.jpg

But please read the django docs on static versus media. Media is for useruploaded content, static is for site-content like css/images.